# Why is my code not displaying boxes on the canvas further along the x after 8 on the y?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im trying to create a 64 square checkerboard on the html canvas element in javascript.
The problem is i cant seem to get the boxes to render plus 75 on the x axis (posX) after the first 8 have rendered on the y and i cant seem to understand what im doing wrong.

Here is the code i have been trying.

```
<body>
 
    <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script src="js/main.js" ></script>
</body>

#mainCanvas {
  background-color: black; }


const canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const sWidth = 75;
const sHeight =75;
const sCount = 64;
let posY = 0;
let posX = 0;

function DrawSquare(posX,posY,color){
    console.log(`Drawing square at (${posX}, ${posY}) with color ${color}`);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(posX, posY, sWidth, sHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

for(let i = 0;i < sCount;i++){

    if(i % 2  == 0){
    
        DrawSquare(posX, posY,"white");
        console.log("white"+posX)
     }else{
        DrawSquare(posX, posY,"black");
        console.log("black")
     }


     if(i>7){
        if(i%8==0){
            posX+=75;
         }
      }
     posY+=75;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated and a thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably also reset  `posY = 0`,`if(i%8==0){`

Comment: You have put me on the right track thank you so much.

Comment: @kikon with your help i accomplished  what i wanted thank you so much again. https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/tjgkr5on/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [kikon noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851162/why-is-my-code-not-displaying-boxes-on-the-canvas-further-along-the-x-after-8-on#comment133794240_75851162), resetting the `posY` to 0 after every 8 squares is what you needed to do.

However, if you're just drawing black and white squares, and you have a black background, you only need to draw 32 the white squares. After that, just detect when the column you're on is alternating from the start to know when to draw at `posY = 0` vs `posY = squareHeight` (or in this case, 75px).

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const squareWidth = 75;
const squareHeight = 75;
const squareCount = 32;
let posY = 0;
let posX = 0;

function DrawSquare(posX, posY, color) {
  //console.log(`Drawing square at (${posX}, ${posY}) with color ${color}`);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(posX, posY, squareWidth, squareHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

for (let i = 0; i <= squareCount; i++) {
  DrawSquare(posX, posY, "white");

  if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
    let isColumnEven = ((i / 4) % 2) == 0;
    if (isColumnEven) {
      posY = 0
    } else {
      posY = squareHeight
    }
    posX += squareWidth;
    continue;
  }

  // Move down a distance of 2 squareHeights
  // because you are skipping the black squares
  posY += squareHeight * 2;
}
```

```css
#mainCanvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your'e answer is very good and accurate but i want 64 squares in my use case at a later point.